# how to tell compiler that a name is a template type name?

Tags: c++, templates

For example I got code like this:

```
#include <iostream>
class Bar {
 public:
  class Foo {
   public:
    static void print() {
      std::cout << "hello" << std::endl;
    }
  };
};

template<typename Type, typename MemberType>
class Test {
 public:
  Test() {
    Type::MemberType::print();
  }
};

int main() {
  Bar::Foo::print();
  Test<Bar, Bar::Foo> test;
}
```

when compiling, the compiler told me that `no member named 'MemberType' in 'Bar'`, it trying to find the literal name "MemberType" other than what is actual is.

How can fix this problem?

Comment: Try `MemberType::print();`. `MemberType` is `Bar::Foo` already.

Comment: You can't. This isn't preprocessing where `MemberType` is just a token to be replaced. It's the actual type, fully resolved already.

Comment: Why not simply `template<typename MemberType> struct Test { Test() { MemberType::print(); } };`?

Comment: And I'm more curious about why are you doing something like this? What is the underlying and actual problem you want to solve this way?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude let me simplify the actual problem, it is a little complicated

Comment: `MemberType` is already fully resolved as a `Bar::Foo`. You don't need to have an extra redundant `Type`.

Comment: I'm sorry, after simplified my actual problem I found that I got a design pattern problem.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a X/Y problem.

Answer (score 1):

This line here is the Problem

```
Type::MemberType::print();
```

just change it to

```
MemberType::print();
```

and it'll work.

the problem is, when you say `Type::MemberType::print();`, the cpp compiler wont know that you mean `MemberType` that you sent, it'll simply search for it inside the `Type`, it'll search for `MemberType` and not `Foo`.